# What implements Bouncy Castle's DatagramTransport?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, bouncycastle, dtls

I'm trying to write a simple DTLS client in C# using Bouncy Castle.

I've found only one example use of the API I think I need in the library's own tests: `crypto/test/src/crypto/tls/test/DtlsProtocolTest.cs`.
The network layer in the test is mocked by `MockDatagramAssociation`, which contains a `MockDatagramTransport`. This transport class implements `DatagramTransport`, which is the parameter type required by `DtlsClientProtocol.Connect()`. Finally, `DtlsTransport` returned by `.Connect()` exposes the `Send()`/`Receive()` API familiar from plain UDP.

The tricky thing is that I can't find any other implementation of `DatagramTransport` other than the mock. It's even more strange, as the Java Bouncy Castle does indeed have a `UDPTransport` implementing `DatagramTransport`.

I admit .Net and C# are not among my strong skills, therefore I might be missing something that's obvious to anyone knowing the ecosystem better.

Where do I find a `DatagramTransport` implementation for UDP?
Is the library user expected to provide a project-specific implementation on their own?
Is there any external library implementing it or is it a part of .Net itself?

Comment: `DtlsRecordLayer` implements `DatagramTransport`. But I think the answer is yes, you provide your own implementation of DatagramTransport for the transport. It seems to be trivial to implement for UDP.